# rails validation before action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

Here's what happens in my app:

- customer enters phone number
- phone number is searched in customer model to see if it exists
- if it does exist, go to the customer show page
- if it does not exist, go to customer new page to create new customer

According to my understanding, model validations are for data that is entered/edited/deleted into the database.

**However, how can we check (use the validation) before anything searches in the database?** And if it is incorrect (example: using letters instead of digits for phone number), then would show the error.

I was implementing html form input options to prevent someone from inputting letters in the phone number input box like this:

```
 <%= form_tag(new_customer_path, method: :get) do %>
   <%= telephone_field_tag :phone, nil, placeholder: "Phone Number", required: true, pattern: "[0-9]{10}", title: "Number must be 10 digits", maxlength: "10", class: "input-lg" %>
   <%= submit_tag "Enter", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
 <% end %>
```

However my form was getting big because I would then put the html form input box options on everything (phone, zip-code, email, ect.).

**What is more proper "Rails" way? Using active record validations to show errors, or providing html form input options to validate the data beforehand? Or is it the combination of both (max secure? client side and before database)?**

Model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :phone, :email
  validates :phone, :zip_code, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
  validates_length_of :phone, is: 10
  validates_length_of :zip_code, is: 5
end
```

Controller

```
def new
   if @customer = Customer.find_by(phone: params[:phone])
    flash[:success] = "Welcome back"         
    redirect_to @customer
  else
    @customer = Customer.new(phone: params[:phone])
    flash.now[:warning] = "Customer not found, please sign up!"
  end
end
```

error messages partial

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><%= value %></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rails validation is probably good enough but if you're worried about it you could add a javascript validation on the client side. There are several plugins you could use if you want to do form validations client side or you could write your own. This might be helpful: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just add front end validations with JavaScript and HTML. Your Rails validations looks fine.

Html: `required` attribute.

Jquery: Check out this link - http://jqueryvalidation.org/